# How does C++ trailing return type help in virtual functions?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, trailing-return-type

There is a statement in C++ Hight Performance book:

> The trailing return is necessary in some contexts. For example, if we are writing a virtual function, or the function declaration is put in a header file and the function definition is in a .cpp file.

How does trailing return type help in those two cases?
Cannot find anything about that.

Comment: No trailing return type and virtual functions are not directly related. I mostly use it in (C++17 and earlier) template functions with SFINAE since the deduction rules for the return type can be quite complex and using an auto return type with trailing return type deduction is much more readable. It's main use is for cases like this `template <typename FirstType, typename SecondType> auto add(FirstType a, SecondType b) -> decltype(a + b){ return a + b; }`

Comment: It doesn't help with those. It's possible that this quote was taken out of a wider context, or that the book is just wrong. (I believe Packt Publishing is one of those companies that churn out less-than-brilliant books by the hundreds.)

Comment: Virtual functions existed in C++ for decades before the trailing return type was invented. Which serves to demonstrate that the latter is in no way necessary for the former. Same with declaring a function in a header and defining in a source file. The sentence quoted makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: [CppReference says this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function): Trailing return type, useful if the return type depends on argument names, such as `template<class T, class U> auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u);` or is complicated, such as in `auto fpif(int)->int(*)(int)`. It says nothing about the two cases in the OP.

Comment: `struct Foo { auto bar(); };` will need the trailing return type, `struct Foo { auto bar() -> int; };`.

Answer (score 1):

The trailing return type can lookup inside the class whereas the leading return type would be in the namespace scope for the out-of-class definition of a member function.

For example:

```cpp
struct S {
    using type = int;
    type f();
};

type S::f() {  // Error: type not declared in this scope
}

// You need: `S::type S::f() {}`

auto S::f() -> type {  // OK: finds S::type
}
```

If your return type is very complicated (usually templated and dependent), you might be forced to use a trailing return type, e.g.:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct S {
    template<typename U>
    static U g();

    decltype(g<T>()) f();
};

template<typename T>
decltype(S<T>::template g<T>()) S<T>::f() {  // Error: does not match
}

template<typename T>
auto S<T>::f() -> decltype(g<T>()) {  // OK
}
```

---

These are an example for the second half of the quote "or the function declaration is put in a header file and the function definition is in a .cpp file".

There should be no difference between a virtual and a non-virtual member function's use of a trailing return type. Though virtual functions typically do have an out-of-line declaration, so maybe that's what it is referring to?